# How to have inner class inherit fields from outer wrapper?

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

We want to be able to have the inner wrapper class inherit fields from the outer wrapper class.

How can we do this?

Current setup:

```
public class ContactWrapper {
  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
  public String email;
  public List<RelatedContactWrapper> relatedWrappers;

  public class RelatedContactWrapper {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String email;
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
public class ContactWrapper {
  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
  public String email;
  public List<RelatedContactWrapper> relatedWrappers;

  public class RelatedContactWrapper {
    // inherit from ContactWrapper
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try to avoid adding tags which have nothing to do with what you are working on. The `[community]` tag is intended for questions about the **[`Communities`](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_overview.htm&language=en_us)** feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make it `virtual`.

```
public virtual with sharing class Outer
{
    String foo, bar, baz;
    
    public class Inner extends Outer
    {
        public Inner()
        {
            foo = 'abc';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but virtual is no longer necessary (and may actually cause compile errors).

Comment: Please clarify. It should not be possible to extend a class which is neither `abstract` nor `virtual`, and compiler errors based on `virtual` usage would be extremely disturbing.

Comment: Hmm, something else may have triggered that. I was working on a different project where I had a top-level class marked as virtual and got the error "classes are virtual by default." ... But I just tried this and it worked after changing the name (Outer is apparently now a reserved keyword). Might be version dependent I guess.

Comment: Sounds like you may have accidentally mixed up something you wrote in `Execute Anonymous`, which is the only place I've seen that error.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose so. I guess I learnt something today 

Comment: @AdrianLarson if i removed `public Inner(){foo = 'abc';}` the `inner` class value for `foo` could still be assigned right? for example, `Outer.inner.foo = 'abc123';`

Comment: That syntax is not correct, no.

Answer (score 2):

That's what inheritance does.

Inner classes can extend outer classes, provided your outer class has the required modifier (`abstract` or `virtual`)